# Formatar String para inserir no Mysql (TIMESTAMP)

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso inserir uma *string* que está assim:

```
"2014-11-25T14:13:35.000Z"
```

em um banco MySql e usando PHP em um campo `TIMESTAMP`.

Como posso formatar a *string* para a inserção usando PHP?

Comment: Você pode usar a função `sprintf` http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Se isso não fosse uma data -OU- não tivesse a definição de *timezone* (.000Z), sim. Queria saber como ficaria com a DateTime, mas depois do que eu sofri da última vez mexendo com timezones com ela, não vou nem tentar. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode também fazer assim, utilizando a função que o Silvio comentou com a função [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) para formatar antes de fazer a inserção no banco de dados:

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2014-11-25T14:13:35.000Z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2014-11-25T14:13:35.000Z"); // 1416924815
```